# Nivo Slider having problem in Chrome & Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins

I'm using Nivo slider on [this page](http://doskins.com/test/test.html). The problem is that the slider collapses in chrome and safari. What I need to change?

Secondly, I want to change the title and links on each new images. How will I accomplish this? Will I use "afterChange" method? I've to load images dynamically using some server-side language (PHP). Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#nivo-slider is supposed to have a height and width specified, you're applying dimentions to its parent container, #nivo-slider-wrapper.

If you have more than one question the best practice is to post them separatedly.

Comment: Thanks! :) I'll be careful about that!

Answer (score 1):

Hey. I can't help with the afterChange method, but I can help with the collapsing issues you are having.

Try putting the following in your **styles.css**:

```
#slider {
     min-height: 400px; //or whatever height you require.
}
```

And then alter your html for displaying the nivoSlider to:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
     //other nivo stuff here.
</div>
```

Should solve the collapsing problem. Good luck :)