# image slideshow doesn't work with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

This image slideshow works in all browser but not in Google Chrome
http://www.example.com

Any idea how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be your issue:

[Nivo Slider having problem in Chrome & Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824140/nivo-slider-having-problem-in-chrome-safari)

```
#nivo-slider is supposed to have a height and width specified
```

Comment: Just confirmed this by playing with the styles on the page - I think you need a width of 1001px and height of 230px

Comment: I just tryed doing that but i still have the same problem... I don't know what i did wrong :(